# Block-style formatting of multi-line control statements in clang-format

Tags: c++, c, clang-format

I'm trying to format long control statement conditions using clang-format like so:

```c
if (
    some_library_prefix_long_contrived_example_function(foo, bar, baz) != 12345
    && x > 10
) {
    x = 10;
    do_something(x);
}
```

I've tried to play around with all the [style options](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html), but no matter what clang-format always seems to wrap these conditions like this:

```c
if (some_library_prefix_long_contrived_example_function(foo, bar, baz) != 12345
    && x > 10) {
    x = 10;
    do_something(x);
}
```

The break position around the logical operators (`BreakBeforeBinaryOperators`) and the opening brace (`BraceWrapping -> AfterControlStatement`) can be changed, but I can't find an option to control breaking around the parentheses. Is there a way to achieve the first style in clang-format?

Comment: Sorry to say this, it's impossible. This is available only to function arguments.

Comment: Ah okay. I had a feeling this was the case since even `BlockIndent` is a newer option. Thanks.